# Docker : Cannot find module when running NextJS app in a docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

So I am trying to run a [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment) app inside a docker-compose.

In order to have a NextJS boilerplate + a Docker image to build the container, I followed the steps provided in [the docker example of the NextJS official repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker).

Here is the provided Dockerfile :

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size 
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

From there, I created a `docker-compose.yml` file at the root of the app, and try to write it myself so that it starts the NextJS app :

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - 3004:3000
```

However, when running `sudo docker-compose up --build`, I get the following error :

```
 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
   throw err;
   ^
 
 Error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: []
 }
```

Why is it not able to find the node modules? What am I doing wrong exactly?

Comment: When you map `./:/app` you map your current host directory onto /app in the container. When you do that, whatever was in /app in the container becomes hidden and inaccessible.

Comment: @HansKilian I see, thank you! What do I have to do then? remove the line `./:/app` ? Just tried it, didn't work

Comment: Try removing all 3 mappings

Comment: This works indeed after I removed the volumes ! thank you!

But is this optimized? I thought I needed these for optimization?

Comment: I don't think those mappings will optimize anything. Optimization of what?

Comment: In fact I think they are useful for hot reloading. Without them I believe I lose that feature.

Comment: Dockerfiles that build an image ready for deployment (which yours is) and Dockerfiles that do hot reloading look very different. In my experience, you can't do both at the same time.

Comment: Okay I see, I'm a Docker newbie so I don't understand everything I'm doing yet. 
I'm trying to achieve hot reloading thanks to tutorials like this one : https://binyamin.medium.com/docker-live-hot-reloading-with-next-js-bf3aa0c6b798 or even that one : https://jameschambers.co.uk/nextjs-hot-reload-docker-development

They both use volume mapping as a way to get hot reloading if I understand correctly

Comment: Yes. When you do hot reloading, you map your source into the container rather than copy it. You also build at runtime rather than build-time.

Comment: @HansKilian removing volumes really helps, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is my docker file from the same boiler plate which is working for me.

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
RUN export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && yarn build && yarn install --production --ignore-scripts --prefer-offline

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
# COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# USER nextjs

ENV PORT=80
EXPOSE 80

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I have commented # USER nextjs as nextjs user was not working.

And this is my dockerignore file

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env.development
**/.git
**/.github
**/.husky
**/.idea
**/.next
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-d
```